# How do you trigger an event when a specific object from an array is instantiated?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At my game's start, a game object from the array is randomly instantiated. I want to make a series of if statements stating that if a specific number from the array is instantiated, then it will perform a function specific to the object instantiated, but I have been unsuccessful. For example, if object 2 from the array is instantiated, then it would do something like make the screen red, and if object 3 is instantiated, then the screen will turn purple.

So far I've tried many things, but this was the most recent:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (playerPrefab[0])
        {
            Debug.Log("weiner");
        }
    }
```

Here's some of my other code

```
public GameObject[] playerPrefab;
public GameObject[] enemyPrefab;

public Transform playerSpawn;
public Transform enemySpawn;

Unit playerUnit;
Unit enemyUnit;

public BattleHUD playerHUD;
public BattleHUD enemyHUD;

public BattleState state;

void Start()
{
    state = BattleState.START;
    StartCoroutine(SetupBattle());
}


IEnumerator SetupBattle()
{
    randomInt = Random.Range(0, playerPrefab.Length);
    GameObject playerGO = Instantiate(playerPrefab[randomInt], playerSpawn);
    playerUnit = playerGO.GetComponent<Unit>();

    randomInt = Random.Range(0, enemyPrefab.Length);
    GameObject enemyGO = Instantiate(enemyPrefab[randomInt], enemySpawn);
    enemyUnit = enemyGO.GetComponent<Unit>();
```

Comment: This smells like homework help.  :)  Per the [guidelines about topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), it helps to describe what you've tried so far, and why it's not working or your difficulty with that approach.  For example, in your SetupBattle function, you have access to the randomInt.  Can you create a function that does your If checks, then call it inside SetupBattle as soon as you have the randomInt?

Comment: The thing is that apparently I can't get a working if check. How would you suggest I create the if check? If you're still curious, I put my most recent attempt in the post. Also, this isn't for hw, lmao

Comment: How about doing the if check right after assigning your value to `randomInt` inside the SetupBattle() method, before or after you call Instantiate?  `if (randomInt == 2) { /* Do work here */ }`

Comment: thats genius, it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sean Skelly answered the question

"How about doing the if check right after assigning your value to randomInt inside the SetupBattle() method, before or after you call Instantiate? if (randomInt == 2) { /* Do work here */ }"